# how to get the list of all links in a revision in MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki-api

I was wondering if it was a way in the MediaWiki API to get the links for a given revision of a page. For instance, if I send this request: [action=query&prop=links&format=json&indexpageids=&revids=120227341](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=links&format=json&indexpageids=&revids=120227341)

I get all the links from the "Oakhill College". But what I want to do is to get the links for the same article let say the 7 May 2014. the revid is now 607467544, so I do the following request: [action=query&prop=links&format=json&indexpageids=&revids=607467544](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=links&format=json&indexpageids=&revids=607467544)

This give the links for the same article, at the same date than before. But I want the links present in the article at the date of the 7 May 2014. Someone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki caches links and other "side results" of wikitext parsing in the database. That only covers the current version of articles and `prop=links`, like most API results, is based on that, so there is no way to tell it to use an old revision. If you want to do that, you need to re-parse the old wikitext. See the [parse API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse), especially the `oldid` and `links` parameters. ([API sandbox example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&oldid=120227341&prop=links))